# How to resolve eslint(vue/html-closing-bracket-newline) conflict

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, visual-studio-code, eslint-plugin-vue

On save, VSCode is fixing eslint is fixing all the rules. How to fix the below conflict?

**Expected Indentation**

[image: Expected Indentation]

**Unexpected Indentation**

[image: Unexpected Indentation]

**VScode Plugins in use:**

```
 [
    "formulahendry.auto-close-tag",
    "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome",
    "hookyqr.beautify",
    "mikestead.dotenv",
    "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "donjayamanne.githistory",
    "eamodio.gitlens",
    "sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate",
    "ecmel.vscode-html-css",
    "abusaidm.html-snippets",
    "wix.vscode-import-cost",
    "lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter",
    "eg2.vscode-npm-script",
    "christian-kohler.npm-intellisense",
    "sibiraj-s.vscode-scss-formatter",
    "octref.vetur",
    "blanu.vscode-styled-jsx",
    "jcbuisson.vue",
    "hollowtree.vue-snippets",
    "wscats.vue",
    "sdras.vue-vscode-snippets",
    "dariofuzinato.vue-peek",
]
```

**Error**

[image: Error]

**Here is the config in use:**

```
 'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': [
  'error',
  {
    singleline: 'never',
    multiline: 'never'
  }
],
'indent': ['error', 2],
'vue/html-indent': ['error', 2],
'vue/script-indent': ['error', 2],
'vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline': 0
```

**VSCode settings**

```
 {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html",
        "plaintext": "jade",
        "edge": "html"
    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "javascript": "jsx"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/tmp": true,
        "**/.bin": true,
        "**/.next": true,
        "**/__snapshots__/**": true,
        "**/coverage/**": true,
        "**/report/**": true
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,
    "files.exclude": {
        ".next": true,
        "*.log": true,
        "**/__pycache__": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/o": true,
        "dist": true,
        "geckodriver.log": true,
        "package-lock.json": true,
        "yarn.lock": true
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.find.globalFindClipboard": true,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        // For ESLint
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
        // For TSLint
        "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
        // For Stylelint
        "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
    },
    "launch": {},
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
    "javascript.validate.enable": true,
    "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "prettier.disableLanguages": [],
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "vscode-typescript",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
    "eslint.validate": [
        "vue",
        "html",
        "javascript",
        "typescript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescriptreact"
    ]
}
```

- Multiline formatting should be retained, but the closing bracket should
  be in the same line itself as expected from the image.
- There should be no conflict between eslint and vscode settings
- Require necessary vscode settings.
  and eslint settings for vue setup Also, the sass files should not get affected with alignments every time on pre-commit checks.
- It will be good if tab alignments are considered instead of 2 spaces for vue, js and sass files

Comment: Sick and tired of these conflicts. Is there no solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already done this, but did you follow this?: https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/linting-error.html#linting-error-checking to either change eslint to use essentials only, or to override the plugin's fixed linting settings and make sure template validation is off?

Comment: After following the vetur guidelines from the provided link: 1. Still the HTML tag is closing next line. 2. vue-cli-service lint --fix is not throwing any lint errors even the template files with 2 space is not fixing. I need indentation to be fixed to tabs during lint time which runs on pre-commit hooks.

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa: I am still getting "Multiline formatting should be retained, but the closing bracket should be in the same line itself as expected from the image." issue. Any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 space/tab is a pain and its a challenge to fix. Hence sticking to 2 space along with few changes in settings to match my requirement.

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
  },
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "plaintext": "jade",
    "edge": "html"
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
  },
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/tmp": true,
    "**/.bin": true,
    "**/.next": true,
    "**/__snapshots__/**": true,
    "**/coverage/**": true,
    "**/report/**": true
  },
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,
  "files.exclude": {
    ".next": true,
    "*.log": true,
    "**/__pycache__": true,
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/o": true,
    "dist": true,
    "geckodriver.log": true,
    "package-lock.json": true,
    "yarn.lock": true
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.find.globalFindClipboard": true,
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    // For ESLint
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    // For TSLint
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
    // For Stylelint
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
  "launch": {},
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
  "javascript.validate.enable": true,
  "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false,
  "editor.insertSpaces": false,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "prettier.disableLanguages": [],
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettyhtml",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.postcss": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.less": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.stylus": "stylus-supremacy",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts": "prettier",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.sass": "sass-formatter",
  "vetur.validation.template": true,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "prettyhtml": {
      "printWidth": 100, // No line exceeds 100 characters
      "singleQuote": false // Prefer double quotes over single quotes
    }
  },
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "html", "vue"],
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [".js", ".vue"]
  },
  "eslint.probe": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "html",
    "vue"
  ]
}
```

**package.json devDependencies**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-import": "0.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-es-beautifier": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-modules": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fibers": "4.0.2",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^25.4.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "sass": "1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11"
  },
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true
  },

  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', '@vue/standard'],

  rules: {
    quotes: [
      2,
      'single',
      {
        avoidEscape: true
      }
    ],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': [
      'error',
      {
        vars: 'all',
        varsIgnorePattern: 'css',
        args: 'all'
      }
    ],
    'no-use-before-define': [
      'error',
      {
        functions: false,
        classes: true
      }
    ],
    'no-var': 'error',
    'prefer-const': 2,
    eqeqeq: [
      'error',
      'always',
      {
        null: 'ignore'
      }
    ],
    'no-array-constructor': 'error',
    'no-new-object': 'error',
    'no-bitwise': 'error',
    'no-redeclare': 2,
    'no-proto': 2,
    'no-invalid-regexp': 2,
    'vue/script-indent': ['error', 2],
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: 'never',
        multiline: 'always'
      }
    ],
    'space-before-function-paren': [2, 'never'],
    'no-new': 0,
    'no-implied-eval': 0,
    'handle-callback-err': 0,
    'no-extend-native': 0,
    indent: ['error', 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
    semi: [2, 'always'],
    'vue/html-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        attribute: 1,
        baseIndent: 1,
        closeBracket: 0,
        alignAttributesVertically: true,
        ignores: ['pre', 'textarea', 'span']
      }
    ],
    'no-tabs': 0,
    'vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline': [
      'error',
      {
        ignoreWhenNoAttributes: true,
        ignoreWhenEmpty: true,
        ignores: ['pre', 'textarea', 'span']
      }
    ]
  },

  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },

  globals: {
    console: true,
    alert: true,
    document: true,
    __dirname: true,
    require: true,
    window: true,
    process: true,
    module: true,
    define: true,
    _: true,
    Promise: true,
    setTimeout: true,
    clearTimeout: true,
    mount: true,
    clearInterval: true,
    setInterval: true,
    $: false,
    MutationObserver: false,
    Map: false,
    localStorage: true
  }
};
```

**.prettierrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  tabWidth: 2
};
```

**.jshintrc**

```
{
    "esversion": 9
}
```

**.editorconfig**

```
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

**That's it, and everything working as per expectations. Hope this helps someone.**

Comment: Het which extensions you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

you can config .prettierrc.js

```
bracketSameLine: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your config to this, hopefully it should allow what you are trying to do:

```
{
  "vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": ["error", {
    "singleline": "never",
    "multiline": "always"
  }]
}
```

If you want to read more about it, please refer [this](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/html-closing-bracket-newline.md).

Answer (score 0):

Add in .eslintrc under the rules:

```
rules: {
  "prettier/prettier": [
    "warn",
      {
        htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "ignore"
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if I have understood correctly, what you need is to use in your eslint extends:

```
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/standard',
  ]
```

which have pretty much everything you need for a sane formatting.

**Keep in mind you have to install them**

My vs-code settings just have the default formatter

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
...
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
...
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

And nothing else related to this matter - I hope this helps.

Comment: Error: Failed to load config "@vue/standard

Comment: You need to install them first.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/eslint-config-standard
&&
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposed solution is leading a lot of dependency installation not helping me to resolve

Comment: I am sorry, but what I am suggesting is the preferred and recommended way. Whatever else is most likely spaghetti. If you use Vue cli everything is out of the box for you to work.

Comment: I am just looking for closing tag same line with a tab indentation

Comment: I understand that. Installing the recommended vue eslint rules, will help you.

Comment: I should turn off just one particular rule and support for tabs properly because eslint/vue has a conflict with 4 space indentation.